# Solr Aggregation with abs()

Tags: solr

I have a solr schema having the following fields

```
<field name="company" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
<field name="profit_amount" type="double" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="false"/>
```

I am doing a stats-facet query to aggregate "profit_amount" field on "company" field.

For one of my use case I need to aggregate only negative values of "profit_amount" field. So I am using filter query as `fq=profit_amount[* TO 0]` and my json.facet is `{"profit_amount-company":{"terms":{"field":"company","limit":10000,"mincount":1,"facet":{"profit_amount":{"query":{"q":"profit_amount:[* TO *]","facet":{"sum":"sum(profit_amount)"}}}}}}}`

Since all my profit_amount is negative, I am getting a negative amount grouped for each company. My requirement is I want the values to be returned as positive, how can I use abs() function in Solr to achieve the same.

Comment: Did you try `sum(abs(profit_amount))` as the facet sum function call?

Comment: Thank you @MatsLindh it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine the functions as [shown in Yonik's examples](http://yonik.com/json-facet-api/): `sum(abs(profit_amount))` as the facet function should work.